# How do i render a react component passed in as a props with additional props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Foo component inside Bar component

```
import Foo from './foo';    
<Bar component={Foo}>
```

Now, i want to render this.props.component with additional props, foobar = 'LOL';

Something like this

```
<this.props.component foobar='LOL'/>
```

I found 3 ways to do it.

Clone

```
render(){ 
let newFoo = {...this.props.component}
newFoo.props = {...newFoo.props, foobar: 'LOL'}}
return(<div> {newFoo}</div>);}
```

But i don't want to clone.

Callback

```
render(){ 
!this.props.component.props.foobar&&this.props.addPropsToFoo(foobar: 'LOL');
return(<div> {this.props.component}</div>);
```

But, i do not want to use callback in this case.

HOC, but i'm intern and this is advanced guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are having a component like

```
import Foo from './foo';    
<Bar component={Foo}>
```

You won't be having any props in `Foo` because of which you can render the component `Foo` as below

```
const Comp = this.props.component;

<Comp foobar='LOL' />
```

This way you are not cloning the component as well.

Comment: You said “You won't be having any props in Foo,” but this behavior has nothing to do with whether or not `Foo` has props. This is confusing to new learners.

Comment: The only purpose for that was they need not worry on props of Foo

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Foo component inside Bar component

```js
import Foo from './foo';    
<Bar component={Foo}>
```

To be clear, it looks like `Foo` is a variable holding a reference to a class or a function—in other words, a component definition, and not an instance of a component. Since that's the case, you would create an instance of it using `React.createElement`—in fact, the JSX you show is just syntactic sugar for this command:

```js
React.createElement(component, props)
```

You can actually still use JSX for this though, you just need to use a capitalized variable name for the function/class, which informs Babel to keep the reference as a variable instead of transforming it into a class (e.g. `React.createElement(SomeVariable)` versus `React.createElement("div")`):

```
const Example = ({ component: Component }) => 
  <Component otherProps="here" />
```

`React.cloneElement`, meanwhile, is used when you have an instance of a component already:

```
React.render(<Example component={<Foo withProps="here" />, someElement)

const Example = ({ component }) => 
  React.cloneElement(component, { additionalProps: "here" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional props to Bar component

```
<Bar component={Foo} componentProps={{foobar: 'LOL'}}>
```

Later you can use these props

```
<this.props.component foobar={this.props.componentProps.foobar}/>
```